# What is the mount point for an FTP server opened in nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, ftp

My question is what is the mount point in nautilus opening ftp server (example: ctrl + L ftp://ftpserver.com) like DVD/CD was in /media/Optical, or Pendrive was on /media/Mypendrive for example.
I looked in /media /mnt and other folders but did not find

Comment: this is primarily an English site. I see your other question is in English - could you translate this one please? It will have a far greater chance of being answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mount point is in `$HOME/.gvfs/`, a virtual file system that is only accessible by the user who owns the session.

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu 12.10, the mount point for FTP and other flying mounts, is under`/run/user/{USERNAME}/gvfs/`, and accessible by session owner.